# How to use explode() with php variables

Tags: php, arrays, explode

I'm using a html table where each row and column has his own ID (e.g. `name="23_3"`).
But this ID is made of 2 variables `$calUser= $x['idTask'] . "-" . $y['idTime'];`

This is how I `explode()` it:

```
list($uTask,$uTime) = explode("-", $_POST['$calUser'], 2);
```

But it's not working any ideas?

## EDIT

Sorry forgot the `input`

```
<input type='text' name='" . $calUser . "' value='$calUser'>
```

Comment: How is it not working?

Comment: (Probably) Because it's not `$_POST['$calUser']` but `$_POST['calUser']`.

Comment: Did you mean `$_POST['calUser']`?

Comment: This is my `<input>` where it is used:
`<input type='text' name='" . $calUser .  "' value='$calUser'>`

Comment: Edit your question and add the "input" please...

Comment: One possible issue: the `name` attribute of an input _must_ start with a letter. Yours seem to start with numbers.

Comment: Underscore or hyphen with `explode` function?

Comment: I tried this : `$calUser= "a".$x['idTask'] . "a" . $y['idTime'];` an the explode : `list($uTask,$uTime) = explode("a", $_POST[$calUser], 2);` but it's not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input in your case should be:

```
<input type='text' name='calUser' value='". $calUser . "'>
```

Validate this by taking a look at the produced page's soure code.

After that you can get the content by calling:

```
list($uTask,$uTime) = explode("-", $_POST['calUser'], 2);
```

But as with all user provided content ($_POST), check if the content really is within the range of expected values to prevent XSS and injection attacks on your page.

Answer (score 0):

Fist of all, you are trying to explode $calUser, or the value corresponding to the $calUser key?.

I think you should do:

```
list($uTask,$uTime) = explode("-", $_POST[$calUser], 2);
```

Remove the quotes on the $_POST key, or you will be asking for the literal '$calUser'

**EDIT**

Also, your input tag must be:

```
<input type='text' name='" . $calUser . "' value='" . $calUser  ."'>
```

Altough i dont know if rou are using a string for the tag, or directly echoing to ouput, so some like:

```
<?php
echo "<input type='text' name='" . $calUser . "' value='" . $calUser ."'>";
```

Would be advised, and my favorite syntax:

```
<?php
echo "<input type='text' name='{$calUser}' value='{$calUser}'>";
```

I like the brackets, as are more friendly even with SQL...

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I still get nothing when I try to `echo` `$uTask`